# Regex to match strings containing "+" in IIS URL Rewrite Module

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of url's that I would like to rewrite in my IIS with the URL Rewrite module.
The urls looks like this: `http://domain.com/randomstring+endrandomstring`. The catch here is the "+" sign. It ruins everything.

I've tried to match it with following regex, and even though the module says that my urls are a match, it doesn't redirect when I try it live in a browser: Regex: `randomstring\+endrandomstring`.
I've tried grouping, end ($) and beginning (^). All which the module accepts as a match but doesn't work live. Also tried with the url encoded version `%2B`. No luck.

Does the "+" sign have some kindda wierd url formatting or maybe its reserved character of some kind?

The "test pattern" function in the module accepts my regex as a match:

[image: +][image]

Comment: Try with `[+]` instead of `\+`

Comment: `+` is a special placeholder for the space character in urls and is a special character (quantifier) in regex, please clarify what you're asking and which strings you tried where (browser, regex tester, rewrite module, etc). That said, I've always had a lot of trouble with the IIS rewrite module, and I haven't used it in a loooong time.

Comment: @CodeJockey Not sure how I can clarify any more. But i've added two pictures. Sorry to hear about your bad experience. I'm pretty sure its my only option here :S

Comment: @SabujHassan the module's test function accepts [+] as a match, but doesn't work when I test it live :( But thanks for the try.

Comment: Since people with more experience aren't flocking to help you, I'll take at least one more stab :-P -- in the urls you are testing through the browser, try using the urlencoded version of `+` (I think `%2B`) - not sure how "standard" it is, but if you didn't know or understand from my previous comment, when you type a `+` in a url, it is very often interpreted as a space character by the server. The "test" data in your images might simulate _after_ the "interpretation" process, so it might all be working correctly. Thus, a browser-submitted `+` might be run through that rule as a space (?)

Comment: @CodeJockey "in the urls you are testing through the browser, try using the urlencoded version of +". You mean I should put %2B in my regex instead of +? I already tried that, doesn't work. Only match is if you type string%2Bstring. I agree with you on the last thing. I fear that too. But then I should be able to replace + with a regex space character/whitespace right?

Comment: I'm assuming you are testing through the browser against the IIS server. If so, then in the browser, type `http://domain.com/string%2Bstring`, while having `string+string` in your regex. Tell me if that triggers the rule. --- Then, type `http://domain.com/string+string` in the browser with `string string` in your regex. Tell me if that triggers the rule. --- This will be tricky pretty much no matter how you cut it because it appears you are trying to use a url format that is typically interpreted differently than it is typed.

Comment: @CodeJockey sorry for the late reply. Been on holidays. None of your examples triggers the rewrite. `string string` is triggered with `http://domain.com/string%20string` so I was hopeing it would match `http://domain.com/string+string` aswell. But no luck. I'm afraid this is impossible. Do you agree?